# Error while importing Database Library in robot framework in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

I am importing DatabaseLibrary in the Robot Framework in Pycharm but it's showing Unresolved Module. I have tried all possible reasons from my side but unable to resolve this problem.

> Unresolved library: DatabaseLibrary. Error generating libspec: Importing library 'DatabaseLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DatabaseLibrary' Consider adding the needed paths to the "robot.pythonpath" setting and calling the "Robot Framework: Clear caches and restart" action.

Please help me out from this.

I have tried installing `pip install robotframework-databaseLibrary`
and much more that i can not explain that here in writing.

Comment: Hello @Maaz, you haven't provided enough information so these articles could be good starting points to figure out the issue: https://blog.finxter.com/fixed-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-robotframework-databaselibrary/ and https://docs.robotframework.org/docs/different_libraries/database

Comment: Hello @Pramesh, Now This Library is working for my one Project in Pycharm but not for another. What should I do?  I already tried methods that you suggested me, like to install Library using CLI. This is showing  "Requirement already satisfied: robotframework-databaselibrary in c:\python312\lib\site-packages (1.4.4)".

Comment: Hello, could you please explain what kind of error messages you are getting? If you are getting the same `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DatabaseLibrary'`, then you could try running your project using `python -m robot your_project` as suggested here: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#toc-entry-237

Comment: @Pramesh Yes brother i am getting same Error for same Library but in different Pycharm Projects. Running the project is other thing. Here Keywords of that Library are not calling, they showing error.

Comment: If it is working in one project but not in another, then you should try to figure out what the differences are between 2 projects (for example python versions etc). You could also try to perform the "Robot Framework: Clear caches and restart" action on your Robot Language Server or Robot Code settings. If you tried everything and still not working then you could always [log an issue](https://github.com/MarketSquare/Robotframework-Database-Library/issues).